# Use an alert to trigger an Azure Automation runbook no data

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-monitoring, azure-runbook, azure-alerts

I want to run a runbook with the output of an alert. I followed the steps from the documentation but i don't get any output. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-alert-triggered-runbook

Can anyone helpe me please?

Answer (score 0):

If your runbook is exactly the same as the one thats shown in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-alert-triggered-runbook) document then as that runbook have only Write-Verbose / Write-Error commands (but not Write-Output commands) so you would not be shown any user-specific output (except OperationID, Status, StartTime and EndTime) only in case

1. your runbook is published but you didn't turn on verbose logging under 'Logging and tracing' tile of your runbook settings.
2. your runbook is unpublished and you have tested the runbook using Test pane but you didn't set VerbosePreference variable to continue in runbook.